# Three20 for iPad

Tags: iphone, three20, ipad

I have a requirement of using Three20 in my iPad project. I was wondering if the Three20 project of iPhone version is directly usable in iPad or should we wait for the this timeline to complete:

http://three20.info/timeline/roadmap

Are there any alternatives for Three20 in OS 3.2?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am also building an iPad app with three20 and started using the master git repository. Big mistake. There were a lot of problems that were driving me crazy! It is from the fact that three20 has a lot of hard-coded values that assume iPhone screen sizes. So some views do not line up or even work at all in iPad.

I have since started using the iPad forked version of three20 at http://github.com/sixten/three20/tree/ipad-master with much better luck.

Comment: I have used the old iPhone version of Three20 and made changes to it so that it fits in for iPad. I had only small requirement of Three20 in my project so I was able to tweak Three20 sources for my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Old three20 really has some problems just like what you mentioned here. But I ran the latest samples on iPad simulator , seem all went well.

Comment: I have used three2o library in ipad everything works perfect also rotation (Landscape & portraite )