# Using UIImagePickerController on the iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm developing an iPad app for use in-house. It's basically a SplitView based app, with a list of items. The details view contains a navigation controller. When the user selects an item in the rootview, it displays the definition of that item in the details view.

I want them to be able to drill-down into a gallery of images for that item, and be presented with a UI similar to the iPad photos app. Basically thumbnails with the ability to view it at original size and then go back to the thumbnails.

I was looking at using the UIImagePickerController but it looks like you need to use that in a Popover control, is that the case? It also looks like you can also only use it with pictures stored in the photo area on the iPad.

The images I use are downloaded to the iPad at startup, if it makes the whole thing do-able, can I save them into the users photo's area? As an album for each item?

Failing all of that, is there a nice clean, simple solution that would meet my requirements? I've tried using the Three20 solution but couldn't get it to work with my SplitView. Can the OOTB UIImagePickerController do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three20 right now is not iPad ready, for your requirement, you can **fine-tune** Three20 and use it to display the original size images, and then pop-back to view controller which shows the thumbnail images.

Comment: Do you know of any articles to help with this? I'm by now means an Obj-C expert so I'd probably end up breaking it rather than fine-tuning it!!

Comment: There arent much articles dealing with this. Three20 for iPad is still under construction and I guess it is not yet ready for use, this is the reason why I too had to fine tune it. Check the link in my earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998024/three20-for-ipad. Fine tuning Three20 is suggested rather than re-implementing your own slide show stuff. Or perhaps, find any other open source solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Three20 in a modal view controller with a pagesheet or formsheet preeentation style.