# Building iOS app with Facebook/Twitter-like design

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ipad, web-applications, twitter

I am starting development on an iOS app for iPad, and I am looking to build the app with a similar design to the current Facebook or Twitter iPad apps. The functionality that I am looking for, specifically, is the ability to have a menu on the left side that can be shown or hidden with a swipe, and content on the right side that layers over the menu. I have looked at doing this app with a split-view controller, but I see no way of layering content like in these other apps. I'm not even sure what to call this style of app, so any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Examples of layered content:

Facebook:
[image: Facebook for iPad, menu visible]
[image: Facebook for iPad, menu hidden]

Twitter:

Although I can't pull the image from it, this link has a good image of the layered content panes in the Twitter iPad app.

https://twitter.com/#!/download/ipad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an open source library for iPad that gives the same functionality of the Twitter app, stacking tableViews with swipe gestures, Here is the link to the github repo:

https://github.com/aaronbrethorst/StackScrollView

Answer (score 4):

if you are specifically looking for the slide effect of view on swipe you should check out this sample project http://www.appdesignvault.com/downloads/PhotopadSampleProject.zip from AppDesignVault.

They have a very similar effect as in Twitter.. I think with some minor modification you can implement that in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to three20: http://three20.info/, https://github.com/facebook/three20, since it was the library used for the Facebook app.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't believe that three20 is used any more for the FB app, although it was at one point.

Comment: From what I can tell, it looks like three20 is used for the iPod/iPhone apps, but it doesn't look like it's used for the iPad app. I also checked the [ipad-master branch](https://github.com/sixten/three20/tree/ipad-master) of three20 (as per [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998024/three20-for-ipad)), but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: I researched it as well and you're right. I'm sorry for not being able to help further.